# Max value of a expression

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> given $M\subset\mathbb{R}$ where $M=\{|z^2+az-1|:z\in\mathbb{C}\wedge|z|=1\},a\in\mathbb{R}$ find max value of $M$ in function of $a$

i tried to make $z=e^{\theta i}$
$$\begin{align}
|z^2+az-1|&=|(e^{\theta i})^2+ae^{\theta i}-1|\\
&=|e^{2\theta i}+ae^{\theta i}-1|\\
&=|\cos2\theta+i\sin2\theta+a\cos\theta+ai\sin\theta-1|\\
&=|(\cos2\theta+a\cos\theta-1)+i(\sin2\theta+a\sin\theta)|\\
&=\sqrt{(\cos2\theta+a\cos\theta-1)^2+(\sin2\theta+a\sin\theta)^2}
\end{align}$$
what i can do next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: $|z^2+az-1| = |e^{i2\theta}+ae^{i\theta}-1| = |e^{i\theta}| \cdot |e^{i\theta}+a-e^{-i\theta}| = 1 \cdot |a+2i\sin\theta|$.

What value of $\sin \theta$ maximizes $|a+2i\sin\theta|$?